# Create dynamic filenames via sas macro variables

Tags: sas, filenames

I am in the process of creating dynamic webfiles via a stored process. The ouput file are generated via proc stream. However I am doing something wrong whilest creating the dynamic file paths.
The following simplified example works:

```
FILENAME hello 'D:\test\hello.html';
proc stream outfile=hello; begin
    hello world
;;;;
```

However when I try to dynamically create files using a do loop, I am not getting any output at all. (no errors as well)

```
%do i=1 %to 3;
    %let outputFileName = D:\test\&i%str(.html);
    FILENAME hello '&outputFileName';
    proc stream outfile=hello;   begin
        Hello world
    ;;;;
%end;
```

If I put the outputFileName variable, I can see my path is the way it is supposed to be.

Any ideas?

Comment: Bangs head against wall. Can't believe I have been this blind. Thanksfor the help DWal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macro variable reference won't resolve inside single quotes. Use double quotes:

```
FILENAME hello "&outputFileName";
```